# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on custom library

Tags: android, shared-libraries, aar

I created a library and this library use another external library (just one).

This is the configuration of my library:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile ('com.github.Paroca72:sc-gauges:3.0.1') {
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

Export the library, as .aar, using gradle -> :library -> assembleRelease.
Now iclude the library in a new project using "import .JAR/.AAR package" and including it in "module dependency"..

In the coding phase I no have errors but when I try to start the application I have this kind of exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sccomponents.codes.gauges.ScArcGauge" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.test-oKxgn-etFOgh1n6SqKQU5Q==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Referred to the external library "com.sccomponents.codes.gauges.ScArcGauge" that was include in my own library..

What wrong?

I'm using Android Studio (latest version)

Comment: Can you show me the generated code in the app module's build.gradle? The line where you have the import for your library added by Android Studio

Comment: Try after enable multidex .

Comment: This is the gradle of the library:
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('library-release.aar'))

And this the inclusion in the project:
implementation project(':gr001')

Comment: I already tried to enable multidex everywhere but without success.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely when you included your library via Android Studio you ended up with something like

```
compile 'yourlibrary":1.0.0@aar'
```

So it means that only the aar will be pulled in and not your dependencies. You need to change it to

```
compile ('yourlibrary":1.0.0@aar'){ transitive=true }
```

Comment: The external library inside my library is: compile ('com.github.Paroca72:sc-gauges:3.0.1') {
        transitive=true
    }.. I must add @aar on this?

Comment: No you don't. Your library's gradle seems fine. Maybe you have problem with including it. Try to remove any extra stuff from your app build.gradle, clean the project and add the library back. Who knows, might help

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps.

1. Right click on your project and select Properties.
2. Select Java Build Path from the menu on the left.
3. Select the Order and Export tab.
4. From the list make sure the libraries or external jars you added to your project are checked.
5. Finally, clean your project & run.

May be because its not added the library at run time.

Comment: Very sorry: I forget to said that I'm using Android Studio